# Form validation angularjs inside ng-template script

Tags: angularjs, html, forms, validation

I want to validate name field in this code..

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="add.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">ADD</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="add-table">
            <form name="myForm">
                <tr>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <td>
                            <label>name:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name"
                                placeholder="Name" required=""></input>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.name.$dirty">Required</span>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                </tr>
            </form>

        </table>
    </div>
</script>
```

The expression `myForm.name.$dirty` does not evaluate and return any value.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you describe the issue that you're having?

Comment: <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.name.$dirty">Required</span>
ng-show="myForm.name.$dirty" never become true.
$dirty,$error never evaluate.

Comment: Nothing appears to be wrong.

Comment: why this is not working?

Comment: Create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) or add a code snippet to your OP.

Comment: Please note that this same code works perfectly if I put it in HTML(i.e. myForm.name.$dirty is evaluating correctly), instead of script; putting it in ng-template script is causing some problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try moving your `<table>` inside the `<form>`.
2. Also try using
   `$invalid` instead of `$dirty`.